# Weight balancer on java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Life needs a balance: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        int pounds;
        int weights;

        // User input
        System.out.print("How many pounds does the item weights? ");
        pounds = input.nextInt();



        // Calculation
        int amount = pounds;
        System.out.println("you need " + amount  + " weights in total:");


        int hundred = pounds/100;
        int fifty  = pounds/50;
        int twenty = pounds/20;
        int ten = twenty/2;
        int five = ten/2;
        int one = five/1;

        // Invoice
        System.out.println(hundred+" 100 lbs");
        System.out.println(fifty+" 50 lbs");
        System.out.println(twenty+" 20 lbs");
        System.out.println(ten+" 10 lbs");
        System.out.println(five+" 5 lbs");
        System.out.println(one+" 1 lbs" );
    }
```

Does anybody know what could be the problem? every time I am trying to make it work it only displays weird weights such as:
If an Item is 99 pounds , the display output is:

Life needs a balance:

How many pounds does the item weights? 99

you need 99 weights in total:

0 100 lbs

1 50 lbs

4 20 lbs

2 10 lbs

1 5 lbs

1 1 lbs

Comment: The logic here doesn't make sense. What is `one = five/1` supposed to be doing?

Comment: 99 / 100 = 0,99 and since you are saving it as a int the result will be 0. Are the missing digits after the decimal point your problem, if not please tell us your desired results

Comment: You never use 'weights' variable, your question is not clear, can you explain what you want exactly? what inputs you should to give and what output you should to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you're looking for could be the following:

```
public static void printWeights(int pounds) {
    int[] weights = new int[]{100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1};
    int[] appearance = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        while (pounds >= weights[i]) {
            appearance[i]++;
            pounds -= weights[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(appearance[0] +" times 100 lbs");
    System.out.println(appearance[1] +" times 50 lbs");
    System.out.println(appearance[2] +" times 20 lbs");
    System.out.println(appearance[3] +" times 10 lbs");
    System.out.println(appearance[4] +" times 5 lbs");
    System.out.println(appearance[5] +" times 1 lbs" );

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("How many pounds does the item weights? ");
    int pounds = input.nextInt();
    printWeights(pounds);
}
>printWeights(99);
>>0 times 100 lbs
>>1 times 50 lbs
>>2 times 20 lbs
>>0 times 10 lbs
>>1 times 5 lbs
>>4 times 1 lbs
```

The original mistake was that the code resulted in printing how many weights can we take not to get more than the original weight. What you should do, is to check how many 100s fill, each time you find that another one fits subtract 100 from the weight which is left and mark, that we take one 100 more. When no 100 fits, repeat with 50s, then 20s etc.

Comment: but now there is a syntax error because if I input 5 for the weight, It will only display (4 times 1 lbs).

Comment: @ManuelAlejandroAlcalá I changed one `>` to `>=`. Now should be correct. It was a typo